# Does GCP charge for external static IP?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Google Cloud offers a free tier which includes Compute Engine. If I setup a static external IP on this instance, will I be charged, or will I be covered by the free tier?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a customer service question. [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Official [Google Cloud Free Program](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier) documentation, it states under [Free Tier usage limit](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier-usage-limits) for Compute Engine,
`Google Cloud Free Tier does not include external IP addresses.` same as using a GPU for your instance. Meaning you won't be able to change/update it (in-use External IP addresses for f1-micro instance).

Also, take note on this one:

> Free Tier: All Google Cloud customers can use select Google Cloud
> products—like Compute Engine, Cloud Storage, and BigQuery—free of
> charge, within specified monthly usage limits. When you stay within
> the Free Tier limits, these resources are not charged against your
> Free Trial credits or to your Cloud Billing account's payment method
> after your trial ends.

Comment: According to new GCP free tier documentation: Compute Engine free tier does not charge for an external IP address. So you get 1 external ip for free.